# Running Spark + Scala + Jupyter on Dataproc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-toree

I haven't yet managed to get Spark, Scala, and Jupyter to co-operate. Does anyone have a simple recipe? Which version of each component did you use?

Comment: Instead you can use zeppelin

Comment: Indeed, that is a good alternative which worked out of the box. But wow, half a gigabyte for a notebook? What are they doing? I'll keep this question open until someone shows how to get Jupyter to work with Scala and Spark. In the meantime, I'll use Zeppelin. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It supports many interpreters which are bundled in the same binary because of which zeppelin binary is very large.But they will be removing this interpreter in 0.6 release and provide external utility to install interpreter that user needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Toree](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree/) is compatible with DataProc's 1.0 image, which currently includes Spark 1.6.1. I had unsuccessfully tried to use it with the preview image, which includes Spark 2.0 preview. To install Toree on the DataProc master you can run

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user jupyter
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
pip3 install --pre --user toree
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
jupyter toree install --user --spark_home=$SPARK_HOME
```

Comment: Interesting. Their version documentation implies it shouldn't be compatible: https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree#version.

Comment: 1.6.1 fits "1.5.1+", which is what they say. At least it _seems_ to work; I've just started testing.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is included standard on Dataproc clusters.

Here is a gcloud command you can use to create a Dataproc cluster (named "dplab") that includes Jupyter listening on port 8124:

```
$ gcloud dataproc clusters create dplab \
 --initialization-actions \
     gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
 --metadata "JUPYTER_PORT=8124" \
 --zone=us-central1-c
```

Then run this command to port-forward from your host to the cluster master:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh dplab-m \
 --ssh-flag="-Llocalhost:8124:localhost:8124" --zone=us-central1-c
```

Open localhost:8124 in your browser and you should see the Jupyter page.

Comment: Great. Where's Scala?